# UI Automation doesn't work in Windows Phone 8 app.

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, microsoft-ui-automation, narrator

I developed an app for Windows Phone 8 some time ago. The client wants the app to be accessible for Blind users.

I have given "AutomationProperties.Name" values to all the app elements, but Narrator doesn't detect the elements at all. It detects the main window of the app but none of its containers and items.

I made a new app and narrator detects all the controls I put in there.

I have not been able to find any help on this topic  anywhere and any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Windows 8 doesn't support this feature. I upgraded my target OS to 8.1 and narrator is working just fine.